# X-Frame-Option Allow https:://Somewebsite fails in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, iframe, confluence, content-security-policy, x-frame-options

I am trying to  a confluence webpage where I have placed the http header like below:

X-Frame-Option ALLOW-FROM https://SomeWebsite.
and 
Content-Security-Policy as 
default-src\ 'self';\ connect-src\ *;\ font-src\ *;\ frame-src\ *;\ img-src\ *\ data:;\ media-src\ *;\ object-src\ *;\ script-src\ *\ 'unsafe-inline'\ 'unsafe-eval';\ style-src\ *\ 'unsafe-inline';

Now everything works fine in chrome. But in IE and Edge, for some page where the content opens in a message box or sort, fails to load with the below error:
SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by res://ieframe.dll/forbidframing.htm

Answer (score 0):

It works in Chrome because Chrome, Firefox and others don't implement ALLOW-FROM. Instead they (and Edge >= 15) implement the frame-ancestors directive in Content-Security-Policy 2.0 and if present they ignore X-Frame-Options.

IE and Edge will show that message when the page being framed has an X-Frame-Options header that doesn't allow it to be displayed where requested. Check your URI including scheme and port. Implementing it with frame-ancestors in CSP may give you a more accurate error message in other browsers.

Comment: well, the X-Frame-Option is set to ALLOW-FROM https://SomeWebsite. Which means it is allowing me to iframe into somewebsite.com but not working in the original application.